# Flex child to determind parent's width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a parent with a `flex` child :

```css
.card {
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 80vw;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 32.5vw;
  z-index: 100001;
}

.menusC {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="menusC">
    <div class="menuBC">
      ......
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see my flex is `inline-flex` which means the flex get the size of its items.
But the parent `card` insist to have it's own width (takes the max otherwise 100%).
**How would i make the `card` - be exactly at the width of the flex**  - `menusC` ?

Comment: I have not seen how code is executed display looks like but why parent has fixed position with left and right set to 0 which means we are asking it to go left to right all the way. Maybe change position fixed to something else and also try removing left or right if fixed is needed.

Comment: yes that's it, sorry but it was a stupid mistake of a beginner. Thanks. You can post it and i will accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen what it looks like when the code is executed, but why has the parent got a fixed position with `left` and `right` set to `0`?

This is telling it to go all the way from left to right.

Maybe change `position: fixed` to something else, or remove the `left` or `right` properties if fixed position is needed.